# PHPUnit: How to assert that a class extends another class?

Tags: php, phpunit

In my PHPUnit test, I would like to assert that the class that I am testing extends another class. How can I do this with PHPUnit?

Answer (score 20):

Use [`assertInstanceOf()`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertInstanceOf) instead of PHP's built in `instanceof` operator or functions so that you get a meaningful failure message.

```
function testInstanceOf() {
    $obj = new Foo;
    self::assertInstanceOf('Bar', $obj);
}

...

Failed asserting that <Foo> is an instance of class "Bar".
```

Answer (score 2):

Or also you should use this assert like this:

```
    $this->assertSame(
        'Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType',
        get_parent_class('AppBundle\Form\CarType'),
        'The form does not extend the AbstractType class'
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using instanceof?

-> http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Answer (score 1):

[`is_subclass_of()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) (or possibly [`is_a()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php)) might be what you're looking for.