# Testing class who extends another class(PHPUNIT)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

i'm having problems testing in phpUnit , i have `"class class_A extends Class_B"`

and i don't know how to test that , i tried to mock class b like this

```
$this-> mock = $this-> getmock('class_A',array('Class_B'));
```

but when i run the test ,the test fail and return this

> Missing argument 1 for class_b::__construct(),

anyone have an idea of how i can do it?

(sorry if my English sucks!!)

Comment: i need to test class_A , but class_b ask for his arguments , and i don't know how to mock class_b or what i have to do for class_b not interfere whit the test

Comment: At the end , in this case i have to do :

 $mocking= new class_a($mock ,$mock_parameter_2 );

in order to mock class_B.

and this way it let me test my class_A

Thankyou all!!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[assertInstanceOf](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.0/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertInstanceOf)

(seen in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680164/3454966)

**Edit**: use any valid arguments in the constructor, if you only want to test the inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the constructor as explained in the [docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects):

```
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder('Class_A')
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->getMock();
```

Comment: i have to test class_A , but when i'm trying to test it , the class b ask for the arguments of his constructor , and i want to mock class_b cause i dont need to test that just methods of class_A
(i'm new in phpunit also in php)

Answer (score 0):

I test that the class inherited properly, and that parent functions are there.

```
protected $TestObject;

protected function setUp()
{
    $this->TestObject = new MyLib\Class_B;      // Namespaces being used?
}

public function testClassInstance()
{
    $this->assertInstanceOf('MyLib\Class_A', $this->TestObject);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('MyLib\Class_B', $this->TestObject);
}

// For Instance: These are from the Class A that was extended
public function testClassAWorks()
{
    $this->assertEquals('String', $this->TestObject->GetString(), 'Ensure the Class_A inherited function is returning String');
    $this->assertFalse($this->TestObject->IsFalseFunction());
}

// These are from the Class B
public function testClassBWorks()
{
    $this->assertEquals('Number', $this->TestObject->GetString2(), 'Ensure the Class_B function is returning Number');
    $this->assertTrue($this->TestObject->IsTrueFunction());
}
```